# Which design pattern for making reports in pdf, excel, etc

Tags: java, design-patterns, factory-pattern, strategy-pattern

I have a school project where we must apply some design patterns in java code. I have to make a functionality where data is obtained by JPA/Hibernate and present it in a pdf or excel. I need to make it so that multiple file extensions can be added in the future.

My question is, what design pattern is best used for a pdf/excel report builder like this.

The design patterns I've already looked at is the strategy pattern and the factory pattern(standard, method and abstract).

Comment: You've not really given us much explanation. A Factory pattern decouples code and creates an extensible architecture for adding new extensions. That's about all I can tell you with the question you've written.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the [MVC Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model%E2%80%93view%E2%80%93controller)

It might be suited to your requirements, I would have a different view for PDF and EXCEL files. As you add new file types you could add a new view to handle each of them.

The Controller is the link between your user input and the system, it might take a selection from you for the view you wish to see.

The Model is essentially the data you wish to present in your reports. This should be the same for the pdf or excel report.

The View will be either an excel view which creates the excel file, or a pdf view which creates the pdf file. Both use the model as input.

**Assumption** you have a user interface.

Comment: Hi Paul thanks for your answer.

I forgot to mention that the project is made in JPA, the classes that ensure that a report will be created must be in the domain layer of JPA. I dont't know if MVC will fit in here.

Comment: @Tim JPA should not be a problem to using the MVC pattern.

Comment: Thanks Paul, I will give MVC a try.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. MVC is used for user interface. You actually describe the factory pattern giving the pattern's structures another name to match the MVC pattern. This could confuse things...

Comment: I assumed perhaps incorrectly that there exists a user interface. I had included my assumption as a comment when i first answered. I am not sure why i deleted it :).

Comment: @Rob perhaps you can suggest a better answer/edit

Answer (score 1):

As the question is stated, I suppose you should consider some of the [creational patterns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Creational_pattern). [Factory](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Factory_method_pattern) would probably be the best way to implement the specific functionality.